# angularjs nvd3 dispatch chart event won't trigger $onChanges()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

How do I get `angularjs nvd3 dispatch.elementMouseover` to trigger `$onChanges()` in a child component

.

---

.

**Parent Component Controller (StatsComponent)**

```
class StatsController {

  constructor( $q, PlayerService, PointService ) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$q = $q;
    this.PlayerService = PlayerService;
    this.PointService = PointService;
  }


  $onInit() {

    const P_players = this.PlayerService.getAllPlayer();
    const P_points = this.PointService.getPointLeader();

    this.pointChartOptions = this.setChartOptions();

    this.$q.all([ P_players, P_points ])
      .then(payload => {            
        this.pointLeadersVM = this.getLeadersVM(payload[0], payload[1]);
        this.selectedPointLeader = this.pointLeadersVM[0];
        this.pointData = this.getPointData(payload[1]);
        this.setPointChartMouseOver(this.pointLeadersVM);
      });
  }



  setChartOptions() {
    return {
      chart: {
        type: 'multiBarHorizontalChart',
        height: 300,
        x: function (d) { return d.label; },
        y: function (d) { return d.value; },
        duration: 500,
        multibar: {
          dispatch: {
            elementMouseover: function (e) { /* see setPointChartMouseOver method */ }
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }



  setPointChartMouseOver(pointLeaders) {
    this.pointChartOptions.chart.multibar.dispatch.elementMouseover = function(e) { this.selectedPointLeader = pointLeaders[e.index]; };
  }



  getLeadersVM(players, leaders) {
    // get leaders vm code ...
  }



  getPointData(leaders) {
    // chart data code ...
  }

}

export default StatsController;
```

.

---

.

**Parent Component HTML (StatsComponent)**

```
<leader selectedleader="vm.selectedPointLeader"></leader>
<nvd3 options="vm.pointChartOptions" data="vm.pointData"></nvd3>
```

.

---

.

**Child Component (LeaderComponent)**

```
import controller from './leader.component.controller';
import template from './leader.component.html';
import './leader.component.styl';

const LeaderComponent = {
  bindings: {
    selectedleader: '<'
  },
  template,
  controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
}

export default LeaderComponent;
```

.

---

.

**Child Component Controller (LeaderComponent)**

```
class LeaderComponent {

  $onChanges() {
    console.log('from child component ', this.selectedleader);
  }
}

export default LeaderComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Owwww, figured it out!!!

Inject `$scope` and then call `$scope.$apply()`. Must also use arrow function.

.

---

.

**Parent Component Controller (StatsComponent)**

```
class StatsController {

  constructor( $q, $scope, PlayerService, PointService ) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$q = $q;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.PlayerService = PlayerService;
    this.PointService = PointService;
  }

  // this.$scope.$apply(fn) passing function arg into $apply()

  setPointChartMouseOver(pointLeaders) {
    this.pointChartOptions.chart.multibar.dispatch.elementMouseover = (e) => {
      this.$scope.$apply(() => this.selectedPointLeader = pointLeaders[e.index]);
    };
  }


  // OR this.$scope.$apply() without passing function arg into $apply()


  setPointChartMouseOver(pointLeaders) {
    this.pointChartOptions.chart.multibar.dispatch.elementMouseover = (e) => {
      this.selectedPointLeader = pointLeaders[e.index];
      this.$scope.$apply();
    };
  }
```

article on $apply()
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/